# mibgroup folder is not present in Agent folder

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, mib

While adding private MIBs to the agent, I have created the .c & .h files, which should be kept in the agent/mibgroup folder. But in my case the mibgroup folder is not present, so I created it and kept my .c & .h files within it. After that I execute the

```
./configure --with-mib-modules="dot1qVlanStaticRowStatus"
```

which gives me this error message:

```
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

That means the configure script is not present. My question is, from where do I get this script or mibgroup folder to execute?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `-M+/mib_dir/` to your `snmpconf` before you can do an explicit include of your MIB module.

Example:

`snmpwalk -DlinkTable -v2c -M+../mib/ -m+ALL -c pub localhost:1161 .1.3`